# How to map UID/GID to username/groupname in linux

Tags: c, linux

In a C program on Linux, I get UID and GID of a file, but I want to print the username and group name. So how to map UID/GID to username/group name?

Comment: man getpwuid && man getgrgid

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getpwuid` function to get the username associated with a uid:

```
struct passwd *getpwuid(uid_t uid);
```

The name is returned in `passwd.pw_name`

For groups, use `getgrgid`:

```
struct group *getgrgid(gid_t gid);
```

The name is returned in `group.gr_name`

Comment: @PengFeiLi Does this answer your question?